# Why is there double with the same key in my React-Native FlatList?

Tags: json, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I'm trying to get an object described at the following endpoint : 
https://api.cosmicjs.com/v1/67302ce0-7681-11e9-8193-4bd8888ec129/objects?pretty=true&hide_metafields=true

As you will notice there is a _id field with a unique identifier.

So why do i get :

> "Warning: Encountered two children with the same key, `:`. Keys should
>   be unique so that components maintain their identity across updates.
>   Non-unique keys may cause children to be duplicated and/or omitted —
>   the behavior is unsupported and could change in a future version."

Here is my FlatList render :

```
render() {   
    if(this.props.dataToDisplay.objects){
        console.log(typeof(this.props.dataToDisplay.objects))
        console.log(this.props.dataToDisplay.objects)
        this.props.dataToDisplay.objects.forEach((item)=>{
            console.log(item)
        })

        return (
            <View style={[{backgroundColor: this.state.backgroundColor},styles.container]}>
                <FlatList
                    data={this.props.dataToDisplay.objects}
                    keyExtractor={(item, index)=>{item._id.toString()}}
                    renderItem={({item})=>{
                        <Text id={item._id}>{item.title}</Text>
                    }}
                />
            </View>
        );
}
 else {

    return (
        <View style={[{backgroundColor: 
this.state.backgroundColor},styles.container]}>
            <Text>Loading elements.</Text>
        </View>
      );
    }
  }
}
```

Could there be a problem with the keyExtractor ?
I tried with keyExtractor={(item, index)=>{item._id}} with no results...

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

the `keyExtractor` is ok. the `return` function is not:

```
keyExtractor={(item, index)=>{item._id.toString()}}
```

by opening the curly braces `{}` the engine needs a `return` keyword to return anything. Otherwise it's a `void`

do either:

```
keyExtractor={(item, index)=> item._id.toString()}
```

or:

```
keyExtractor={(item, index)=> { return item._id.toString()}}
```

Same goes for the renderItem method:

```
renderItem={({item})=>{
           <Text id={item._id}>{item.title}</Text>
         }}
```

since you opened the `{}`, you canceled the arrow function's implicit return and you have to append it explicitly

```
renderItem={({item})=>{
        return <Text id={item._id}>{item.title}</Text>
         }}
```

btw,`id` is not one of `<Text/>`'s props. Without the keyExtractor function, you would have to append the `key` property yourself (instead of `id`). feel safe to remove it =)

Comment: Thanks!! I don't have the error anymore ! but it still doesn't render anything : / Even when just trying to render <Text>item !</Text>, nothing print out.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `keyExtractor={(item, index)=>{item.key}}` use `keyExtractor={(item, index)=>index.toString()}`

Comment: Now getting "Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop."
What's strange is that keyExtractor={(item, index)=>{item.key}} is giving me that error too now.
Is there no way to use the _id field of the item to be the key ??

Comment: @JulienFEGER Yes you can give a key to
 renderItem={({item})=>{
      <Text key={item._id} id={item._id}>{item.title}</Text>
    }}

Comment: Problem solved, this up there ;) thanks for your help though.

Answer (score 0):

In your example you don't have any attribute called "key", is for this reason that you have an error. You should be to try assign another attribute like a key element, maybe the attribute "_id", that exists in your object, something like this:

```
<FlatList
data={this.props.dataToDisplay.objects}
keyExtractor={(item, index) => {item._id}}
numColumns={2}
renderItem={({item})=>{
  <Text id={item._id}>{item.title}</Text>
}}
/>
```

Comment: Yeah i tried...even tried to return it as a string with no results :s
Starting to think this is an asynchronous problem with my fetching of the data.

Comment: Do you try to add the key in the Text component? Something like <Text key={item._id} ...

Comment: Maybe you problem is because you are sending in the data prop an object, in the example for FlatList in React-native documentation is necessary send an array of objects for rendering the data: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist/